# How to mock a shadow element in jest testing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, shadow-dom, jsdom

I have a react component `ReactComponentContainer`, which gets config and `shadowRoot`.

```
import React from 'react';
import App from './App';
import ReactComponent from './ReactComponent';

const ReactComponentContainer = function({config, shadowRoot}) {

  configme(shadowRoot.host || shadowRoot);

  return (
    <App renderRoot={shadowRoot}>
      <ReactComponent/>
    </App>
  );
};

export default ReactComponentContainer;
```

In my `jest` test file, I need to mock a shadow dom, so I can pass to ReactComponentContainer as a parameter.

```
const header = document.createElement('header');
const shadowRoot = header.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
shadowRoot.innerHTML = '<h1>Hello Shadow DOM</h1>';
```

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactComponentContainer from './ReactComponentContainer';

describe('ReactComponentContainer', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    setUp = (props) => {
      return mount(<ReactComponentContainer {...props} />);
    };
  });

  it('initailize ReactComponentContainer', () => {

    // mock a shadow dom
    const header = document.createElement('header');
    // Error: attachShadow is undefined
    const shadowRoot = header.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    shadowRoot.innerHTML = '<h1>Hello Shadow DOM</h1>';

    const props = {
      config: {},
      renderRoot: shadowRoot
    };

    const element = setUp(props);
  });
});
```

I am getting `Error: attachShadow is undefined`. I think because it is browser only.

My question:

How do I mock a shadow dom, so I can run it in jest testing?

Comment: why do you try using shadow dom in your test?

Comment: anyway it's JSDOM's reponsibility to implement Shadow API. looks like it could be [already supported](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/2343), just check version you're using in `package-lock.json`(it should be [at least 12.2.0](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/releases/tag/12.2.0))

Answer (score 1):

I used this post to solve the problem for my shadowRoot testing problem in Svelte.
All functions are placed in a separate *CrudTableService.js*.

To run unit-tests with jest and catch the shadow DOM to raise the code coverage I found this solution:

```
it('testSetDeleteMode', async () => {
        const documentHTML = '<!doctype html><html><body>' +
            '<crud-table>' +.     // added for shadow DOM test
            '<div id="options-default"></div>' +
            '<div id="options-delete"></div>' +
            '</crud-table>' +     // added for shadow DOM test
            '</body></html>';
        document.body.innerHTML = documentHTML  // for light DOM tests

        // create shadow DOM for customElement
        const crudTable = document.querySelector('crud-table');
        const shadowRoot = crudTable.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
        shadowRoot.innerHTML = documentHTML;
```